# Postgres syntax in node-postgres for function call

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

Here is how I call postgres from my node.js app using express

```
const db_pg = require("./db-pg");
app.get('/pg/', (req,res,next) => {
    db_pg.query(req).then((body) => {
        res.send(body);
    }).catch((err) => {
        next(err);
    })
});
```

And within my `db-pg/index.js` file (not including the detail of the `pool` setup):

```
module.exports = {
    query: (req) => {
        return pool.query(req);
    }
};
```

I am getting the following error from postgreSQL :

```
syntax error at or near ","
```

The query I am trying to execute is :

```
req = {
    text: "SELECT * from my_func(?,?,?)",
    values: ["the_name", 20190303, 20190620]
}
```

What is wrong in my syntax ?

Comment: Assuming you're using node-postgres, it looks like it should be `"SELECT * FROM my_func($1, $2, $3)"`: https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turning [Chris White](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901755/postgres-syntax-in-node-postgres-for-function-call#comment98466083_55901755)'s comment into an answer:

`node-postgres` recommends to use [parameterized-queries](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query) for passing parameters.

Here is the correct syntax for the SQL (all the rest looks fine):

```
"SELECT * FROM my_func($1, $2, $3)"
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below.

```
req = {
    text: "SELECT * from my_func(?,?,?)",
    values: ["the_name", 20190303, 20190620]
}
```

Comment: wish it were that simple. typo fixed in the question